# Android: Spinner inside Dialog with "text message" when selected

Tags: android, text, dialog, spinner, adapter

I'm trying to change my spinner into: Button > Dialog > Spinner.

Works perfectly, but I can't see messages below (an error occurs and the app closes):

"You have selected English en-us", "You have selected Português pt-br"

Before:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {

            if (pos == 0) { 
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected English en-us", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                setLocale("en");
            } else if (pos == 1) {
                 Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected Português pt-br", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                setLocale("br");
            } 
         }
         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {
        }
     });
}

public void setLocale(String lang)
{
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

My new code:

```
Button bt_lang = (Button) findViewById(R.bt.language);
    bt_lang.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Select Language");
                builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        AdapterView<?> parent = null;
                        switch(which)
                        { 
                            case 0:
                            setLocale("en");
                            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                                    "You have selected English en-us", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();

                            case 1:
                            setLocale("br");
                            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                                    "Você selecionou Português pt-br", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            break;
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                builder.create();
                builder.show();
        }
    });
}
    public void setLocale(String lang)
{
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the app broke"?

Comment: @TenFour04 an error occurs and the app closes

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from the Log?

Comment: here: http://s9.postimg.org/gkea5khwv/image.jpg

Comment: Thanks. For future reference, you can just select those lines from the log and copy/paste them here with keyboard shortcuts. Probably easier than posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an NPE because you initialize `AdapterView<?> parent` as null, and never assign anything to it before using it. You don't need that for the context anyway. In both of your `Toast.makeText()` methods, replace `parent.getContext()` with `MainActivity.this`. An Activity is extended from the context so you can pretty much always just use your activity as the context argument in methods that need a context.